# How to export Magento 2 whole website from live to local?

Tags: magento2

### I just want to know how to export magento2 whole website from live server to localhost ? with proper installation, I tried many shortcuts but failed and faced access denial if hit URL of admin dashboard in local, can anyone please elaborate it step by step, thanks :)

My personal effort before this :

> I have tried and resolve many issues using my own way installing from
>   live to local, I have also faced ioncube encode issue, but resolve it
>   by enabling ioncube in XAMPP with CURL. but my screen return blank
>   screen on both front end and back end dashboard.

Comment: I mean, this is going to depend on your setup... But... FTP your files down, dump your database, import your database locally, set up your env.php to match local credentials, change the base URLs in core_config_data.

Comment: i dont have database file right now for some issues , so i used fresh installation sql file of magento2 setup than run upgrade command for activating extensions for generating further sql files ,and it generates properly , i did changes in env file too but i got blank page with no errors in console neither in running any command. why?

Answer (score 0):

Use proper virtualization and replicate your server. Then just redirect your virtual machine to the domain in question via hosts file.
You don't need to change anything.

See Docker, Vagrant, VirtualBox, ...